Authentication failed error while pulling from TFS through PAT
I have a TFS repo with some source files. Checkout using the username and password works as expected. But when I try with PAT, it shows the error below.
git -c http.sslVerify=false clone https://<username>:<PAT>@<Repo-URL>
Cloning into 'Project'...
fatal: Authentication failed for 'Repo-URL'

PAT has full privileges
Does anyone know what is the exact issue here?

Update
After a further test in a fresh environment, you may authenticate against a base64 encoded PAT.
$PAT = "xxxxxx"

$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$PAT"))

git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: Basic $B64Pat" clone http://aztfs/DefaultCollection/MyProject/_git/MyRepo



I could reproduce the authentication failure when adding the <username> in the repo URL.
It worked from my side if I ran git clone using PAT directly without any username in the repo URL.
$PAT = "xxxxxx"

git clone http://$PAT@aztfs/DefaultCollection/MyProject/_git/MyRepo



it triggers password input while trying with your solution

Hi @Yaseen, Got a chance to check the update answer to authenticate against a Base64 encoded PAT?
